# literal array in SQL statement?

Tags: arrays, literals

I'm sure there must be a really easy way to do this, but I can't figure out how, and a search hasn't yielded a solution.  Here's what I want to do, but it's illegal:

```
update test_table set q_name = {'SKELETAL','LEWIS','MECHANISM', ...}[q_type];
```

That is, `q_type` has an integer value, and I want to populate `q_name` with a string value that depends on the value of `q_type`.  I can do it with a separate set statement for every value of `q_type`, but I'd rather do it with a single call.  Any ideas how to do it without getting into PL/SQL?

Answer (score 0):

The way that I would handle that is using the xml datatype and just populate that xml variable and then update the table from that.

here's the reference on the [xml data type](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/appdev.920/a96616/arxml24.htm)